# ASP.NET DatePicker not working inside GridView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, datepicker

I have a database table with person information that also has their Date of Birth. I'm using `GridView` to display the fields and also using Column edit and delete options. To edit date im using `DatePicker` as follows,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Home Page</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Styles/Main.css'/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#text_date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            inline: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            constrainInput: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            navigationAsDateFormat: true,
            showAnim: "fold",
            yearRange: "c-100:c+10",
            dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#text_dateadd').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            inline: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            constrainInput: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            navigationAsDateFormat: true,
            showAnim: "fold",
            yearRange: "c-100:c+10",
            dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
```

Inside `GridView` within the Columns i have the following. Im using the footer area to insert new data into the `GridView`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date of Birth" SortExpression="DOB">
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="text_date" CssClass="textbox" MaxLength="10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>    
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="label_date" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="text_dateadd" CssClass="textbox" MaxLength="10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But this is not working, I tried clicking on the text fields both within the `EditItemTemplate` and `ItemTemplate` but the calendar wont display. I tried it on a simple web page as below and it works,

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="text_date" CssClass="textbox" MaxLength="10" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</form>
```

Within a normal `div` in a form the date picker works but in the above `GridView` it wont work.. am i doing something wrong? is it because of the `Bind` method? If so how can i solve that? I tried using `div` inside `GridView` also but it wont work.

**EDIT**

The below is the place where i placed my gridview. Im using my grid view within a cell of a table and i also have script manager and update panels

```
<asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="6" Width="100%" Height="100%" VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="update_data" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView></asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:/TableCell>
```

Comment: check in console are you getting any error ?

Comment: no im not getting any errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Finally got a solution.

The problem was not with the `GridView`, it was actually because of using `AutoPostBack` and `UpdatePanel`. It seems `ASP.NET Ajax` and `JQuery` cannot be used together normally. So there was a different solution for that as provided in this link [Conflicts between ASP.NET UpdatePanel and JQuery](https://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/make-them-to-love-each-other-asp-net-ajax-updatepanels-amp-javascript-jquery-functions)

Three methods were provided there and for my application method 2 works fine where we have to add a function `pageLoad()` as below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#text_date').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                inline: true,
                showOtherMonths: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                constrainInput: true,
                firstDay: 1,
                navigationAsDateFormat: true,
                showAnim: "fold",
                yearRange: "c-100:c+10",
                dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

This works fine for all `TextBox` that have post backs and updates combined with`DatePicker`

Answer (score 7):

In this the `TextBox`id will note work because `GridView` will change the id and add it on specific id with it actual `TextBox` Id So try this it will work

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Home Page</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Styles/Main.css'/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.Add-text').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            inline: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            constrainInput: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            navigationAsDateFormat: true,
            showAnim: "fold",
            yearRange: "c-100:c+10",
            dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.Add-text-new').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            inline: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            constrainInput: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            navigationAsDateFormat: true,
            showAnim: "fold",
            yearRange: "c-100:c+10",
            dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
```

Inside `GridView` within the Columns i have just added new class to identify and jquery or javascript will now easily identify it.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date of Birth" SortExpression="DOB">
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="text_date" CssClass="textbox Add-text" MaxLength="10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>    
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="label_date" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="text_dateadd" CssClass="textbox Add-text-new" MaxLength="10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

[image]
[image]

If any query ask me Thanks.

Comment: then use `ClientIDMode="Static"` in your `TextBox`

Comment: but i tried the same..using CssClass and the date picker wont show up when i click textbox

Comment: ok I got it now  try this in your `<asp:TextBox ID="text_date" CssClass="textbox Add-text" MaxLength="10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DOB", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox> `

Comment: in javascript i have to give as `$('.Add-text').datepicker()` or `$('#text_date').datepicker()` when using `ClientIDMode="Static"`?

Comment: use your id and then try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125772/discussion-between-aditya-shrivastava-and-mano-prathibhan-c).

Answer (score 2):

Add a class on the Fields in asp.net as the ID will be dynamically created and will be changed in HTML.
in place of `$('#text_dateadd')` use `$('.dateadd')`

Comment: after execution if you use master page then if you inspect its id suffix somthing ct1000_  etc

Comment: thats why i said add a css class or use this in JS code $('#<% Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("text_dateadd").ClientID%>') , use CSS after trying this option as its clean and readable

Comment: class is also not working...what should i add in place of `ContentPlaceHolder1`? can u give me the correct code format to add this FindControl script with my code?

Comment: share your code ,what is the contentplaceholder id ?

Comment: i have edited my question..added the `GridView` location..within table cell and update panel

Answer (score 1):

Please check id of textbox because in gridview id has changed.
check it view source.

Comment: I have mentioned the same ID in `GridView` and `DatePicker`

Comment: in your web page press F12 key and check for the id of control. use class in place of ID ,there is other way but thats ugly